# Cannot upgrade rsync following distribution upgrade to 20.04LTS

Tags: 20.04

I recently upgraded from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS. The process did not go smoothly and I had to complete it from the command line before Gnome would start up. Now when I enter sudo apt upgrade I get the following error message:

```
sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  rsync
1 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/322 kB of archives.
After this operation, 696 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 299035 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../rsync_3.1.3-8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking rsync (3.1.3-8) over (3.1.3-8) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/rsync_3.1.3-8_amd64.deb (
--unpack):
 unable to install (supposed) new info file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/md5sums': Is a
 directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/rsync_3.1.3-8_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have performed fsck and it comes back clean. Any ideas please?

Steve

Answer (score 0):

Here may occur two problems - rsync archive corruption and/or corruption of `/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/md5sums` structure.

To fix the problems use the commands below:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/md5sums

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @N0rbert. I tried this but it didn't fix the problem. Curiously /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/md5sums does not appear to exist.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall rsync` .

Comment: This results in the same error. Is it safe to purge this package? It notifies me that this will also result in ubuntu-standard being removed, which sounds rather serious.

Comment: Removing the problematic directory by `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci` may help better (do not forget to have *tmp.ci* in the command, otherwise you may harm the system).

Comment: Thank you for your response. The directory /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci does not appear to exist, but I ran the command to remove it anyway. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to fix this so I thought I would post some information in case it is of use to anyone else. The rsync.md5sums 'file' in /var/lib/dpkg/info appeared to be a directory, not owned by root. I don't know how this happened.

```
steve@steve-EP43-DS3L:/var/lib/dpkg/info$ ls -la | grep md5sums
…..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root     1095 Jan 25  2020 rhythmbox.md5sums
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root     2912 Aug 27 04:36 rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar.md5sums
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root    10836 Jan 25  2020 rhythmbox-plugins.md5sums
d--x--S--x 2 26957 31353    4096 Oct 17  2029 rsync.md5sums
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root     3905 Aug  5 01:49 rsyslog.md5sums
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root      923 Mar 24  2019 rtkit.md5sums
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root     4561 Mar 12  2020 rygel.md5sums
…..
```

So I moved the file to my home directory and reran the upgrade, which seems to have been successful.

```
steve@steve-EP43-DS3L:/var/lib/dpkg/info$ sudo mv rsync.md5sums/ ~/
steve@steve-EP43-DS3L:/var/lib/dpkg/info$ sudo apt upgrade
```