# '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/md5sums': Is a directory

Tags: apt, dpkg, md5sum

Trying to update Ubuntu 20.04.
I tried the solution in [Cannot upgrade rsync following distribution upgrade to 20.04LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284691/cannot-upgrade-rsync-following-distribution-upgrade-to-20-04lts)

I tried to `# sudo apt autoclean` and receive warnings for packages:
`dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-49' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed` that I assume is normal after `autoclean`.

Corrently, I get the below error.

```
# sudo apt upgrade
...
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-modules-5.4.0-67-generic' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed<br>
(Reading database ... 605012 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37_2.34.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 (2.34.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) over (2.34.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37_2.34.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
unable to install (supposed) new info file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/md5sums': Is a directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37_2.34.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Same result for `sudo apt-get install --reinstall rsync`

```
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall rsync
...
Suggested packages:
  gstreamer1.0-libav
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 76 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
...
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-modules-5.4.0-72-generic' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-modules-5.4.0-67-generic' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 676780 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37_2.34.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 (2.34.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) over (2.34.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37_2.34.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to install (supposed) new info file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/md5sums': Is a directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37_2.34.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also tried to install `libwebkit2gtk` individually and endup with the same result.

```
# sudo apt-get install libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
...
 '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/md5sums': Is a directory
...
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Run `sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/md5sums ~/ && sudo touch /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci.md5sums && sudo apt -f install`

Comment: Thank you @Someone, I tried your suggestion and the same result!

Comment: Please [edit] to include the result you're talking about. Also, run `sudo rm -r /var/lib/dpkg/info/tmp.ci*` and try running `sudo apt -f install` again (include outputs if it failed).

Comment: I have added more info

Answer (score 0):

**I could finally fix this problem.**

The problem was with a package, in my case "*libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64*".

I could move the package list (**.list**) and checksum (**.md5sums**) files from the original location and update Ubuntu successfully.

**1)** `sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37\:amd64.* ~/`

Generally, you should be able to `sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/<package-name>.* ~/`

then simply run

**2)**

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```